# Where to put Router.events related code in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I am just wondering where I can put Router.events related code in Next.js? Apparently, I can not put it in a specific component, since it needs to be used across the application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put it in a custom App component that is used to init every page.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-app

Here is some example code that subscribes and unsubscribes to a router event :

```
const eventHandler = (url) => {...};

export default class MyApp extends App {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", eventHandler);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", eventHandler);
    }

    ...
}
```

HTH